# USB flash drive doesn't appear in any OS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, partitioning

Hi I got new Kingston DataTraveller drive. I have repartitioned it in OS X than dumped and image of another flash drive on it. Few more times of the same but now it doesn't appear in any OS when I plug it in. Here is output of dmesg | tail in Linux:

```
[17470.869451] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd [17470.987138] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1643
[17470.987142] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3                                                       
[17470.987145] usb 2-2: Product: DataTraveler G3                       
[17470.987147] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Kingston                         
[17470.987148] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 001CC0EC346CFC70C71B2429         
[17470.987590] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0                            
[17472.091870] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4                                             
[17472.092168] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0           
[17472.097092] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg] READ CAPACITY failed                 
[17472.097096] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE                                                
[17472.097100] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]                                                              
[17472.097104] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed                                        
[17472.097713] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off                 
[17472.097716] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00              
[17472.098713] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA 
[17472.103079] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg] READ CAPACITY failed 
[17472.103083] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE 
[17472.103086] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]  
[17472.103089] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed 
[17472.104703] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

So it sees it a little bit and point it to /dev/sdg

If I mount it with mount /dev/sdg /media/usb:

```
mount: /dev/sdg: can't read superblock
```

If I try to fdisk it to see partitions (which it has none) with fdisk /dev/sdg I get this:

```
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdg: Invalid argument
```

If I attempt to zero out the whole disk with dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg

```
dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdg’: No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000208433 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

I can't figure out how to trash entire disk and partition it again correctly. Any ideas?

P.S. Before this began I did manage to format it to ext2 in openSuSe but it threw a bunch of error which I don't remember any more. Windows also sees it as online but total size 0 bytes and won't let me format it.

Alex

Answer (score -1):

To rule out a faulty usb hub or cable, try it on a different computer. If the error persists, the usb drive is likely to be dead.

Comment: Yeah I have tried on a number of different machines and ports. I am just surprised it worked briefly in the first place.

Comment: Different OS, yes. I edited my answer. OP didn't mention a different computer.